# Let $G$ be a set whose each element belongs to some neighborhood of $x$. Can we build a sequence $(x_n)$ in $G$ converging to $x$?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

In proving the equivalence between different definitions of a l.s.c. function, I have come across below question.

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $x \in X$. Let $\mathcal V$ be the collection of all neighborhoods $V$ of $x$. By axiom of choice, there is a function $f:\mathcal V \to X$ such that $f(V) \in V$ for all $V \in \mathcal V$. Let $G := \operatorname{im} f$.

Can we build a sequence $(x_n)$ in $G$ such that $x_n$ converges to $x$?

Comment: You can build a topological net, in fact, $f$ already is such a net, that converges to $x$. To find a converging sequence you need that the topological space is normal, for instance a metric space.

Comment: "Each element belongs to some neighborhood" is a misleading way of putting it. (In fact, this would be trivially satisfied by any set of elements, since the entire space is a neighborhood of your point.) Instead, the situation is that each neighborhood contains some element from your set.

Comment: If $x$ has a numerable basis then it is in fact true but I don't know if the reciprocal is true. In particular, if $X$ is first-countable it would be true.

Comment: No, not always of course.